# Azure egress bandwidth calculation

Tags: azure, networking, bandwidth, calculation

I was wondering how Azure calculates the amount of network bandwidth.  Is it bad ed on the number and size of packets that are moving out of a respective region.  I am asking because I believe if a protocol is chatty or uses encryption, the amount of outbound bandwidth could be significantly larger than the data transferred.